# Extracting and replacing text with a Spannable clickable

Tags: android

@mention functionality like whatsapp

This is a message for :

@9170211268628 hi how are you

Expected :

@Raviraj hi how are you

Comment: are you using adapter??

Comment: I need to replace only textview

Comment: https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/

Answer (score 1):

In [`onBindViewHolder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) of your [`RecyclerView.Adapter<T>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter) implementation, use a [`SpannableStringBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder) to create a new spannable string with the replaced text then call `setText` on the text view.

Answer (score 0):

you want to remove number and comma,
first of all you find out index of comma and then separate string using substring(stratindex,endindex) then put name of user after @.